# How to hide gnuplot axis but still show grid?

Tags: gnuplot

See that black line (depicting the r axis) extending from the centre out to the right? How do I hide it, but still display the (polar) grid?

[image]

Here's the gnuplot syntax:

```
set label '#4' right at screen 0.86, screen 0.88 font 'Helvetica-Bold,34'
set polar
set grid polar back
set xtics nomirror
set ytics nomirror
set rtics scale 0 format ""
set xlabel "Metrology X axis (mm)"
set ylabel "Metrology Y axis (mm)"
set size square
set border 0
set encoding iso_8859_1
set title "80Hz, \26110.00V, mean step size: 23.8\2610.9 um        15 Mar 2017 22:06PM" 
set key outside right
plot '-' using 2:($1/1000.0) t '20', '-' using 2:($1/1000.0) t '50'
```

I'm using Gnuplot v5.0.5 on Linux.

Comment: Add `unset raxis`, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/26297999/2604213